# Spring 5 WebFlux reactive server push notifications using WebSocket

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-websocket, reactor

I would like to know what is right way to implement server push notification using `Spring 5 WebFlux` and `WebSocket` with `Reactor` framework under the hood.

A scenario is the following: clients `A` and `B` are connected to a server (and corresponding `WebSocket` connections `A` and `B` established). Each of the clients could be notified with their own event(s), `event A` or `event B`.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring 5 WebFlux server push notifications via RSocket protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58895471/spring-5-webflux-server-push-notifications-via-rsocket-protocol)

Comment: @Matthias, unfortunately, no, cause these are different protocols